# How to make a new array in numpy, with elements chosen from one array based on another?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

This seems simple, but isn't working for me. I have one array, call it A that I want to choose elements from, based on the index of another array B.

Right now I've been trying:

```
C = A[i for i in B]
```

But that gives me a syntax error. Is there a way to do this properly?

Comment: did `C = A[B]`occur to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With NumPy arrays you can do it directly through fancy indexing:

```
C = A[B]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
C = [A[i] for i in B]
```

Output if 
A=[1,2,3] B=[2,1,0] 
is

```
[3,2,1]
```

Comment: A better method for numpy arrays is given in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You need square bracket around `i for i in B`. Try this.

```
>>> A = np.array([10, 20, 30])
>>> B = [1, 2]
>>> C = A[[i for i in B]]
array([20, 30])
```